# Confusion about Thread life in java program

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a method in which i start a thread and return from method.. Now i am unsure about weather that thread will continue to be in memory after it has completed its execution or it will release memory after completion.

This is my method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testThread", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody JSON_Response testThread(
            @PathParam("name") String name) {
        JSON_Response response = null;
        try {

            System.out.println("name is"+name);

            response = new JSON_Response();
            response.setStatusCode(name);



            TestThread mst = new TestThread(name);
            mst.start();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;

    }
```

This is my Thread class

```
public class TestThread extends Thread{  



    public String inputJSON;
    public static int myCount = 0;


public TestThread(String inputJSON) {
        super();
        this.inputJSON = inputJSON;
    }


public void run(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Expl Thread: "+(++TestThread.myCount));
            Thread.sleep(100);


        } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
            System.out.println("Exception in thread: "+iex.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            printname(inputJSON);
        }

}




public void printname(String name){
    System.out.println(name);
}
}
```

So i want to ask weather after completion of its task it will release memory or not as my method will return before it gets completed.

Comment: It will be eligible for GC when it dies, as will any resources its referencing. P.S. don't extend `Thread`.

Comment: Unrelated to garbage collection, you should consider using the executor framework introduced in Java 5.

Comment: My concern is if my method hits multiple requests then it will keep on creating threads and if its not garbage collected then it will give outofmemory exception @BoristheSpider

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what will happen if the treads keep running for whatever reason. Otherwise, if they are dead, the GC will deal with them.

Comment: I need to allow creation of threads but i am unable to think how to stop a thread after its execution is completed @BoristheSpider can you suggest something

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the thread will be destroyed upon completion; resources will be released.

Of course, someone may still hold a reference to the `Thread` object (not in your case), and that object will not be GC-ed until the reference is cleared. The object itself is not very heavy weight, but it may reference other objects, e.g. through ThreadLocal, and that may retain more garbages; it's especially a problem for class unloading.

Comment: My concern is if my method hits multiple requests then it will keep on creating threads and if its not garbage collected then it will give outofmemory exception

Comment: sure, if you have lots of concurrent threads, JVM may crash. but your framework should have some limit on that; there's usually a thread pool with upper limit; more requests will be queued.